# Device orientation analytics

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, analytics

I am trying to decide if I should implement landscape mode in my application. Is there an analytics software that will tell me if users try to view my app in landscape mode? Or should I write me own methods?

Comment: Hi you should decide according to the number of controls such as Buttons, Text Fields, Labels on your ViewController in such a way that it is easier to handle by a user and gives a good appearance with good expeirience while using app.

Comment: You can provide support for Orientations like UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft, UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight, UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait so the user can use the app in all orientations

Comment: Yes, but I want to to if users really want it before actually coding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [heatma.ps SDK](https://heatma.ps) to view statistics for each screen of your application. It's automatic so you don't have to implement orientation support to find out.

Comment: Grate. So I don't have to code the other interface orientation to know if users want it?

Comment: Yes, it discovers if users tried to view your app in landscape mode even if you don't have it implemented.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell given the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` call is made for all orientations no matter whether the user tries to go to landscape mode, and the willRotate/didRotate callbacks are only made for supported orientations. What you could do is log the

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
```

on each shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation. Or register for the `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` notification. This returns a UIDeviceOrientation, no matter the orientation of you view controllers. Note that this is different from the UIInterfaceOrientation values which UIViewControllers use for the interfaceOrientation property.

```
typedef enum {
   UIDeviceOrientationUnknown,
   UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,
   UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,
   UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft,
   UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,
   UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp,
   UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown
} UIDeviceOrientation;
```

Although the two are related:

```
typedef enum {
   UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait           = UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,
   UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown = UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,
   UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft      = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,
   UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight     = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft
} UIInterfaceOrientation;
```

Comment: Well I know how to code it. But When you have a big application it would be nice to analyze it if users expect it to support other orienations. I was looking for analytics, something like cyprian pointed out.

Comment: I use flurry, its free, easy and powerful. http://www.flurry.com/product/analytics/index.html

Comment: I don't think it supports orientations? Unless I will code orientation discovery and add log event to be sent to flurry.

Comment: You can just log a flurry event when you receive a device orientation change notification. Three lines of code. Depending on how many users you want to track, heatma can be as much as $65/month. Flurry is free.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Analytics User Timings to measure the time interval a user spends in a specific orientation. You can read about tracking user timings for native ios apps at 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/usertimings